# Showing magento product short description on checkout success page

Tags: php, magento

actually i just want to retrieve product short description on checkout success page

As other item show by this code

For example name :

```
<?php foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item) {  }  ?>
<?php $product_id = $item->getData('product_id');  ?>
<?php echo $item->getName() ?>
```

Also i need to show gift wrap amount, currently just found the shipping as

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("core")->currency($order_details->shipping_amount) ?>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: you are writing/displaying your code out of foreach loop

Comment: Yes Joshi is correct. Write the "getData('product_id')"  inside the forloop. Then you can get the description and all the details

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item) {  
 $product_id = $item->getProductId(); //what is this $item->getData('product_id');
 $product = Mage::getModel(catalog/product)->load($product_id);  
 print_r($product->getShortDescription()); }  ?>
```

Better Solution as you `should not load Model every time.`

```
<?php $catModel = Mage::getModel(catalog/product);
     foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item) {  
     $product_id = $item->getProductId(); //what is this $item->getData('product_id');
     $product = $catModel->load($product_id);  
     print_r($product->getShortDescription()); }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add single quote

> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')